# Is there an elegant possibility to include several sets into a multimap?

Tags: c++, set, multimap

I have several sets of the same type:

```
std::set< TDate> spieltagDatum;
```

I would like to include all of them into a multimap of this type:

```
std::multimap<TDate, int> ereignis;
```

Is there an elegant possibility (perhaps with a lambda related function?) to include all members of ONE set into the multimap above not using the iterator mechanism? (The multimap pairs should be enriched with the INT parameter during insert).

Comment: Why don't you like an `iterator mechanism`, I just build a convert iterator class and it looks good.

Comment: I assume, my spelling was wrong - I have mentioned, if there is a STD function that fulfilles this task in a more elegant way that i did via iterators.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest instead of iterators to use simplified for loop with `auto` like below.

I used integer TDate just for example, also instead of `123` in my code you may put any function for filling in values of multimap.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/s8TzexjMP)

```
#include <map>
#include <set>

int main() {
    using TDate = int;
    std::set<TDate> spieltagDatum = {3, 5, 7};
    std::multimap<TDate, int> ereignis;
    for (auto & e: spieltagDatum)
        ereignis.emplace(e, 123);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "not using the iterator mechanism"? (Don't use iterators at your own peril)

As you describe, what you do is to 1) transform (by enrich) and 2) insert, so the answer is `std::tranform + std::insert`.

```cpp
#include <algorithm> // transform
#include <cassert>
#include <map>
#include <set>

int main() {
    using TDate = int;
    std::set<TDate> spieltagDatum = {3, 5, 7};
    std::set<TDate> ...;

    std::multimap<TDate, int> ereignis;

    auto enrich = [](auto e){return std::make_pair(e, 123);};
    std::transform(
        begin(spieltagDatum), end(spieltagDatum), 
        std::inserter(ereignis, end(ereignis)),
        enrich
    );
    ... // repeat for other sets if necessary

    assert( ereignis.find(5) != ereignis.end() );
    assert( ereignis.find(5)->second == 123 );
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zzYbKK83d

---

A more declarative option using libraries, based on @prehistoricpenguin answer is:
(IMO it is worth mainly in C++17, where so many of the templates parameters are not really necessary)

```
#include <cassert>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>

int main() {
    using TDate = int;
    std::set<TDate> spieltagDatum = {3, 5, 7};
    
    auto enriched = [](auto it){
        return boost::transform_iterator(it, [](auto e){return std::pair(e, 123);});
    };

    std::multimap ereignis(
        enriched(begin(spieltagDatum)),
        enriched(end  (spieltagDatum))
    );

    assert( ereignis.find(5) != ereignis.end() );
    assert( ereignis.find(5)->second == 123 );
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6ajssjjjP

Comment: Thank you both for the examples! Both of them work.

As last question, is there a performance advantage for answer 1 as emplace is used instead of insert?

Comment: Thank you both for the examples! Both of them work.

What I don't really understand in the second answer ist, what exactly is done for the enrich variable? It is a pair with the second parameter 123. But which value has the first parameter of the pair?

Comment: @Mauro no, inserter does emplacing if it can. In any case, emplacing is a debatable optimization for associative containers, since you might pay an unnecessary cost if you are inserting a duplicate. You can do your own research on this topic.

Comment: @Mauro `enrich` is not a variable, it is an operation for transform in lambda form. I introduced it to use the same nomenclature as in your question. You can replace it directly as last argument for transform. In all cases the first parameter of the pair is the original value in the set. The operation goes from the value `e` (in the set) to the “enriched” pair (`e`, 123) (potentially inserted in the multimap).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I have understood it now. I was 10 years away from C++ programming (programmed in ABAP only). There were a lot of changes within C++11 and C++14 and C++17 in the meantime...

Comment: @Mauro you missed the best years then :). Lots to learn. It feels like a different language now.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I have programmed a football manager started with Turbo C++ and stopped by Borland C++ Builder 6. Now I have "transformed" the whole game into the Borland Community Edition and it works fine. :-)

Answer (score 1):

One possible answer is to write a convert iterator class, then we use the iterator to constructor the `multimap` instance.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <set>

template <typename KeyT, typename ValT>
class ConvertIter
    : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, std::pair<KeyT, ValT>> {
  using SetIter = typename std::set<KeyT>::iterator;

 public:
  ConvertIter(SetIter itr, ValT v = ValT{}) : _itr(itr), _val(v) {}

  bool operator==(const ConvertIter& other) { return other._itr == _itr; }
  bool operator!=(const ConvertIter& other) { return other._itr != _itr; }

  std::pair<KeyT, ValT> operator*() const {
    return {*_itr, _val};
  }
  ConvertIter& operator++() {
    ++_itr;
    return *this;
  }
  ConvertIter& operator++(int) {
    ++_itr;
    return *this;
  }

 private:
  SetIter _itr;
  ValT _val;
};

int main() {
  using TDate = int;
  std::set<TDate> spieltagDatum = {3, 5, 7};
  std::multimap<TDate, int> ereignis(
      ConvertIter<TDate, int>(spieltagDatum.begin(), 123),
      ConvertIter<TDate, int>(spieltagDatum.end()));

  for (auto [date, val] : ereignis) {
    std::cout << "[" << date << "," << val << "]" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Demo:
https://godbolt.org/z/cr98f15jq

Comment: Or (same idea) use Boost.Iterator `transform_iterator` directly:     `std::multimap<TDate, int> ereignis(boost::make_transform_iterator(begin(spieltagDatum), enrich), boost::make_transform_iterator(end  (spieltagDatum), enrich));`  https://godbolt.org/z/q8195bbvG . Unfortunately this type of code can scare people from using iterators.

Comment: @alfC Thank you for your great code! Boost has so many wonderful utilities but not widely known, I like it! I have spent much time reading the document but still not realize the existence of `make_transform_iterator` :(

Comment: yeah, sadly Boost documentation is too expert-friendly and all over the place. It is hard to find exactly what you need. It is amazing for example that you know how to write an iterator from scratch (an advanced skill) and you didn't know about Boost.Iterator. This tells that Boost has a problem reaching to experts even. I expanded my answer with full Boost-based code.

Comment: @alfC There is no work to do with boost's document system, to make it unified and searchable on the local machine is what I want, something like the `Rust` local document would be perferct.

Comment: @alfC I found that many experienced C++ programmers do not know Boost and have rebuilt many libraries that have been absorbed by Boost, but the code quality cannot reach the high quality of Boost and it is difficult to maintain the codebase. This is a pity.